# External hard drive is full after running AVG PC Tuner, but WinDirStat indicates otherwise

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, disk-space

I recently downloaded AVG PC Tuner, and performed a disk check on my 1 TB external drive. When it completed, it found no issues. However, my hard drive is now almost full when I had about 200‑300 gigabytes free before.

[image: Windows Explorer: 931 GiB total; 894 GiB used; 37.0 GiB free]

I tried running "Disk Cleanup", but it showed nothing to delete.

I then downloaded and ran [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to try and see what's using up the space, but it says I have used only 607 GB: (click for full size)

[image: WinDirStat: 607 GB free]

Can anyone help me reclaim my lost storage space?

Comment: What steps did you follow, exactly, through AVG PC Tuner?

Comment: I just perform the error checking on the external hardrive

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of WinDirStat and Windows Explorer?

Comment: Hi,Please have a look on these 2 links.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/swrtrjanw430zo7/1Capture.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p3poxj628jflum/2Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I know it's too late, but I hope you got the lesson that all those "PC tuner" or "Game booster" apps do more harm than good. If your PC is really slow, buy better hardware instead of such crapware.

Comment: Go to Control Panel > Admin Tools > Computer Management

Under Disk Management, give us a screen shot of your G: drive.


Unless the tool resized your partition to something smaller and then unexpectedly stopped, I don't see how the drive size capacity could change. Maybe you have 300GB of unpartitioned disk space on the 1TB drive.